# JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?

Tags: jquery, duplicates

Say I have a list of links with duplicate values as below:

```
<a href="#">Book</a>
<a href="#">Magazine</a>
<a href="#">Book</a>
<a href="#">Book</a>
<a href="#">DVD</a>
<a href="#">DVD</a>
<a href="#">DVD</a>
<a href="#">Book</a>
```

How would I, using JQuery, remove the dups and be left with the following for example:

```
<a href="#">Book</a>
<a href="#">Magazine</a>
<a href="#">DVD</a>
```

Basically I am looking for a way to remove any duplicate values found and show 1 of each link.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
var seen = {};
$('a').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

**Explanation:**

`seen` is an object which maps any previously seen text to `true`. It functions as a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29) containing all previously seen texts. The line `if (seen[txt])` checks to see if the text is in the set. If so, we've seen this text before, so we remove the link. Otherwise, this is a link text we see for the first time. We add it to the set so that any further links with the same text will be removed.

An alternative way to represent a set is to use an array containing all values. However, this would make it much slower since to see if a value is in the array we'd need to scan the entire array each time. Looking up a key in an object using `seen[txt]` is very fast in comparison.

Comment: Interjay, I thank thee, works perfectly. 

Also, would you mind explaining your code as to understand it?

Comment: @Keith: Added an explanation. I assumed you know what the jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) functions do, so didn't explain those.

Comment: What if I want to match only the last word instead of the entire text? I don't like to pose a new question, so I am asking here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Simple and effective :)

Comment: Use this answer. stay away from the .unique jQuery method as it is useless and did not work for this particular case.

Answer (score 11):

Use jQuery method **$.unique()**

Detail see on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Comment: Why. Why does *the included jQuery method* have 4 upvotes while an 8-line pile of side-effects is sitting at 29 and accepted?

Comment: @Inaimathi: Maybe because this answer is incorrect. If two elements have the same text, `$.unique` will leave them both, so this doesn't do what the question asks. `$.unique` is only useful if you have two references to the same exact DOM element in an array, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Additionally, `$.unique` will only remove entries from an array, it won't remove them from the DOM.

Comment: There is a way to use $.uniqueSort() to perform this task. For an example, see [link](https://jsfiddle.net/s7154r23/).

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, this method is deprecated and just an alias of jQuery.uniqueSort(). Please use that method instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
// use an object as map
var map = {};
$("a").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    if (map[value] == null){
        map[value] = true;
    } else {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@interjay @Georg Fritzsche

Your fix didn't work in my case so I build a different version:

```
var seen='';
   $('a').each(function(){
        var see=$(this).text();
        if(seen.match(see)){
            $(this).remove();}
        else{
            seen=seen+$(this).text();
        }
    });
```

Hopes this provides someone else with a valid alternative short fix just in case.

Comment: I just stumbled on this... There is no reason why @interjay method is not working, plus, this has the potential to cause false positive... Try it if you have 3 links with those texts: "a","b" and "ab", the "ab" link will be removed...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select").each(function () {
       var selectedItem = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').text();
       var selectedItemValue = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').val();
       $(this).children("option").each(function(x){
           if(this.text == selectedItem && $(this).val() != selectedItemValue) {
               $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: am sry , i jst gave idea,,but above piece of code will  retains the selected item & removes the duplicates of selected item.

Answer (score -1):

A quick and easy way would be

```
$("a").​​​​​​​​each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().length)
        $("a:contains('" + $(this).html() + "')").not(this).remove();
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

Nice solution people.
Here is mine

```
for (i = 0; i < $('li').length; i++) {
  text = $('li').get(i);
  for (j = i + 1; j < $('li').length; j++) {
    text_to_compare = $('li').get(j);
    if (text.innerHTML == text_to_compare.innerHTML) {
      $(text_to_compare).remove();
      j--;
      maxlength = $('li').length;
    }
  }
}
```

Greetings

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.photo').each(function (index) { 
    if (index > 0) { 
        $(this).remove(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This would remove every link besides the first 'Book'.