# jQuery Grouping Similar Items w/ Object Literal

Tags: jquery, arrays, structure

So I have this structure setup:

```
<ul>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw1Vh9Yzryo</li> (Vid1)
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOF3o8B292U</li> (Vid2)
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAY4vNJd7A8</li> (Vid3)
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAY4vNJd7A8</li>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw1Vh9Yzryo</li>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOF3o8B292U</li>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAY4vNJd7A8</li>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw1Vh9Yzryo</li>
</ul>
```

Vid1 is repeated 3 times, Vid2 is repeated 3 times, and Vid3 is repeated 2 times. I want to put them into a structure where I can reference them like this:

youtube[0][repeated] = 3;
youtube[0][download] = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=dw1Vh9Yzryo&fmt=36"

youtube[1][repeated] = 3;
youtube[1][download] = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=bOF3o8B292U&fmt=36"

youtube[2][repeated] = 3;
youtube[2][download] = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=yAY4vNJd7A8&fmt=36"

`"This video was repeated " + youtube[0][repeated] + " times and you can download it here: " + youtube[0][download];`

How can I set this multidimensional array up? Been Googling for hours and I don't know how to set it up. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured this out. The structure I needed was achieved by using an **Object Literal**

```
var youtube = {};

function makeDLLink(video)
{
    return "*Download Link*";
}

$('li').each(function() {
    var videoLink = $(this).text();
    var download = makeDLLink(videoLink);
    if (!youtube[videoLink])
    {
        youtube[videoLink] = { "repeated": 1, "download": download };
    }
    else
    {
        youtube[videoLink].repeated += 1;
    }
});

$('ul').append("<br /><br /><br />");
for (var key in youtube)
{
    var obj = youtube[key];
    $('ul').append(key + " was repeated " + obj.repeated + " times and can be DL'd from " + obj.download + "<br /><br />");
}
```

You can see it in action over [at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HQuqg/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements).

```
var seen = {};
$('li').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        seen[txt] += 1;
    else
        seen[txt] = 1;
});
```

Now `seen` looks like

```
{ "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw1Vh9Yzryo": 3,
  "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAY4vNJd7A8": 2,
  [...]
}
```

You can then create a new list:

```
newlist = $('<ul />');
for (var vid in seen) {
    $("<li>This video was repeated " + seen[vid] + " times and you can download it here: " + vid + "</li>").appendTo(newlist);
}
newlist.appendTo(document.body); // or wherever you want it
```

You can see this working on http://jsfiddle.net/CqMcY/

Comment: Most of this was helpful but I'm still a bit confused on making the structure of it all. How could I get the `seen` variable to hold the count and the download link?

Comment: Using the first of the three sections of code in my answer, which looks for `<li>` elements and builds `seen` based upon the contents he finds.

Comment: I built this for you on http://jsfiddle.net/CqMcY/ and you can see it working there.

Comment: Okay so I found out what I'm trying to do for the structure is have a multidimensional array. That would allow me to have something like this:

"Repeated " + youtube[0][repeated] + " times and download at " + youtube[0][download];

This way I have room to add more variables to the mix when the time calls for it. Problem is I don't know how to set that up. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm still having difficulty. What I had shown up there about the YouTube thing isn't what I want but it's very similar. Not only do I have to add a counter for how many times something was repeated but I also need to add to the array a download link (the video links are not the download links) so overall I'm just really confused about the arrays. If you can help me with the multidimensional arrays that would be great help! I'm also confused about the seen variable having {} and the youtube having [].

Comment: Some pointers here: http://www.herongyang.com/JavaScript/Object-Compare-Array-Object-Difference.html. If you feel your question wasn't answered, edit your question to include the new requirements. Or accept this answer :) and ask another question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to get my thoughts together and try to re-word my question to make more sense.