# Find duplicated rows in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a small application with tables like this:

```
<tr>
<td><img class='DeleteButton' alt=delete src='images/delete_icon.png'/></td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td>some Data</td>
<td>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
<td class='toHide'>some Data</td>
</tr>
```

When I add new data in the table, I create a list with "suggestions" - data from the other data tables.

But if I have 3 tables(A,B,C), and some data(D) is in A and B, and when I want to add D to C, in the suggestion list there is D twice.

So how can I find duplicated rows in a table and how to do it the most efficient way?

(only the td-tags without class toHide matters)

So far I have used jQuery to get the suggestion list

```
 $("all the tables").not(myTable).each(function(){
       $(".suggestData table").append($(this).html());
 }
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the question.

Comment: i get the data from different tables and add it to one table, and some of the td-s are dublicated, so i want to find and remove them

Comment: Not sure if that's how you formated the question, but your .suggestData table missing a ".

Comment: that was copy-paste-error in the question, i haven't copy the whole code,i fixed it. The append-function works, i just want to delete the dublicated rows

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: it would be difficult and i don't think it's necessary. I just have a table and i want to know if there are 2 rows, where the data in columns 5,7 and 8 are equal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this post: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234107/remove-duplicate-trs-through-jquery)

Based on the post this is an example:

```
function removeD(w){
    var seen = {};
    if(w == 'val'){
        $('table tr td').each(function() {
            var txt = $(this).text();
            if (seen[txt])
                $(this).remove();
            else
                seen[txt] = true;
        });
    }else{
        $('table tr td').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (seen[id])
                $(this).remove();
            else
                seen[id] = true;
        });
    }
}

$('#removeID').click(function(){
    removeD('id');
});



$('#removeVal').click(function(){
    removeD('val');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHT7A/)

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted. I really have to search better the old questions. There is already answer to almost every question, but I don't find it