# remove duplicate row data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
                <head>
                <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                </head>
                <body>
                <table width="779" border="5" id="test">
                    <tr  class="tablerow">
                        <td>ee</td>    
                        <td>11</td>            
                        <td>test</td>
                        <td>3</td>    
                        <td>15974079
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ww1</td>
                        <td>hi</td>    
                        <td>test2</td>
                        <td>d</td>    
                        <td>15859779    
                     </tr>
                     <tr  class="tablerow">
                        <td>ww2</td>
                        <td>hi</td>      
                        <td>test2</td>
                        <td>t </td>     
                        <td>15974386</td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ww2</td>
                        <td>hi</td>      
                        <td>test4</td>
                        <td>e</td>      
                      <td>15974386</td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ww4</td>
                        <td>hi</td>      
                        <td>test5</td>
                        <td>d</td>      
                        <td>15974652</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>sssd</td>    
                      <td>fgdg</td>      
                      <td>test6</td>      
                      <td>dzz</td>      
                      <td>15974652</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>sssd</td>    
                      <td>d</td>    
                      <td>test7</td>
                      <td>d</td>    
                      <td>15974652</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                <script>
                var arr = $("#test tr");

                $.each(arr, function(i, item) {
                    var currIndex = $("#test tr").eq(i);
                    var matchText = currIndex.children("td").eq(2).text();
                    $(this).nextAll().each(function(i, inItem) {
                        if(matchText===$(this).children("td").eq(2).text()) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>

                </body>maybe is duplicate question but i tried many links and couldn't get my answer.
```

I need to remove duplicate row base on third column, not first one
use eq instead first, but its not work probably,actually in very small table works but when the number or rows and columns get big its doesn't work
for example:
doesn't display forth row even not duplicate when i choose eq(4)or eq(2)
in row "ww4"
i checked this one 
but its only work with first column

[i tried this one too but that one is check all column in row not only base on one columns i need check only value of third row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234107/remove-duplicate-trs-through-jquery)

```
                <head>
                <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                </head>
                <body>
                <table width="779" border="5" id="test">
                    <tr  class="tablerow">
                    <td>ee    
                    <td>11            
                    <td>test
                    <td>    
                    <td>15974079    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>ww1
                    <td>hi    
                    <td>test2
                    <td>    
                    <td>15859779    </tr>
                    <tr  class="tablerow">
                    <td>ww2
                    <td>hi      
                    <td>test2
                    <td>      
                  <td>15974386  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>ww2
                    s<td>hi      
                    <td>test4
                    <td>      
                  <td>15974386  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>ww4
                    <td>hi      
                    <td>test5
                    <td>      
                  <td>15974652  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>sssd    
                      <td>fgdg      
                      <td>test6      
                      <td>dzz      
                      <td>15974652      
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>sssd    
                      <td>    
                      <td>test7
                      <td>    
                  <td>15974652</tr>
                    </table>
                <script>
                var arr = $("#test tr");

                $.each(arr, function(i, item) {
                    var currIndex = $("#test tr").eq(i);
                    var matchText = currIndex.children("td").eq(2).text();
                    $(this).nextAll().each(function(i, inItem) {
                        if(matchText===$(this).children("td").eq(2).text()) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>

                </body>
```

Comment: Invalid Markup: `<td>` is not closed.

Comment: what do you mean, what line then ?

Comment: it means for every <td> you have, you must end with a </td>

Comment: @KuroshSol : what do you mean "what line" ,,, you tell us on which line  you closed the `td` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate <tr>'s through jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234107/remove-duplicate-trs-through-jquery)

Comment: i edit close <td> but nothing change in result

Comment: @LaljiTadhani i tried that one too but that one is check all column in row not   only base on one columns i need check only value of third row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var seen = {};
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).children("td:eq(2)").text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbUxd/440/