# duplicate output of values into table

Tags: jquery

I have the following table that outputs values from db via a loop and looks something like this:

```
<table class="myData">
<tr>
    <td class="lbl">
    Item 1:
    </td>
    <td>
    Amateur Team
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="lbl">
    Item 2:
    </td>
    <td>
    New School
    </td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
    <td class="lbl">
    Item 53:
    </td>
    <td>
    New School
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to use jQuery to highlight duplicate values in the second column, perhaps by changing color. Can that be done?

```
if (duplicate(s)) { 
    $(".myData td:nth-child("2").css("color","red");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements) for an explanation on `seen`

```
var seen = {};
$('.myData td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).css('color','red');
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

Sorry, I just realised this wouldn't highlight the first occurrence. I will fix it up when I get home later tonight if someone else hasn't already answered.

Comment: Very elegant solution @Prowla! My implementation was on the same lines as @icyrockcom, but I discarded when I saw yours!

Comment: Actually this works great for me. I mark only duplicates for removal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Make a map of duplicate count

```
var vals = {};
$(".myData td:nth-child(2)").each(function(i, e) {
    var txt = $(e).text();
    var val = vals[txt];
    vals[txt] = val == null ? 1 : val + 1;
})
```

Mark duplicates

```
$(".myData td:nth-child(2)").each(function(i, e) {
    var txt = $(e).text();
    if(vals[txt] > 1) {
        $(e).css("color","red");
    }
})
```

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vRunH/