# Jquery Array multiple items

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to get a list of items in a page and push them into an array:

```
$('#softwareUpdates article').each(function(index) {    
   productList.push({ 
      class: $(this).attr("class"),
      text: $(this).attr("su_title")
   });
});
```

HOWEVER I want to avoid multiple items, so when I current check the productList array I have:

```
  Item 1, Item1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 3, Item 4
```

What I would like to have is:

```
  Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements

Comment: you could try using `.filter()` first.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the following code from http://hackingon.net/post/Handy-Javascript-array-Extensions-e28093-distinct().aspx.

```
Array.prototype.distinct = function() {
  var derivedArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
    if (!derivedArray.contains(this[i])) {
      derivedArray.push(this[i])
    }
  }
  return derivedArray;
};
```

There are also javascript libraries equivalent to .NET's Linq.  Any of those should work.  Here's one: http://jsinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: This worked but my array is full of objects, is there a way to achieve the same with objects?

Comment: That's why I suggested the Linq clones for JavaScript.  They let you pick and choose values out of an object, then apply the distinct over them.