# Remove duplicate cells of a column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove duplicate cells of a column.

```
<table id="test" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>test1<td>
    <td>test2<td>
    <td>test3<td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>test4<td>
    <td>test2<td>
    <td>test5<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>test6<td>
    <td>test2<td>
    <td>test5<td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>test6<td>
    <td>test8<td>
    <td>test9<td>
    </tr>
    </table>​​​

output
------
test1        test2        test3    
test4        test2        test5    
test6        test2        test9    
test6        test8        test9    


I want in this format
---------------------
test1        test2        test3    
test4                     test5     
test6                     test9    
             test8
```

​

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specifically are you having problems with? What is your question actually?

Comment: you're probably best not to *remove* the cells, just empty them. Removing cells from a table would get messy. real quick.

Comment: why people are downvoting without understanding the question???? I could have done it on my own if it was that simple

Comment: @Tuscan: Probably because you did not show *any* attempt to solve the problem yourself. And to be honest, you did not even ask a question, you just stated what you want. I want a Unicorn.

Comment: I think the problem is an interesting one, but the question could be improved. I suggest you edit your question, explain your problem properly and provide a better (and maybe more concise) example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only removes duplicate text across columns. It works because elements are selected in document order:

```
var seen = {};
$('#test td').each(function() {
    // Encode column and content information.
    var key =  $(this).index() +  $(this).text();
    if (seen[key]) {
        $(this).text('');
    }
    else {
        seen[key] = true;
    }
})​;
```

It probably won't work though if you have cells spanning multiple columns.

Slightly adjusted [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shDpY/1/).

**Update:** For consecutive cells only. The idea is to keep track of the previous value that was seen in one column.

```
var seen = {};
$('#test td').each(function() {
    var index =  $(this).index();
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[index] === txt) {
        $(this).text('');
    }
    else {
        seen[index] = txt;
    }
})​;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shDpY/2/) (note `test5` in the right column)

Comment: Thanx but if there is a mismatch between 2 cells of a column then it should not clear the next cell of the column. e.g if i put test1 in 1st column of 3rd row then it should not be cleared as 1st column of 2nd is mismatched. I am extremely sorry for not explaining the question correctly

Comment: So you only want to clear *consecutive* cells... yes, it would really have helped if you provided an example which clearly shows what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cVBUy/7/)**

```
arr = [];
$('#test td').each(function(){
    key = "" + $(this).index() + $.trim($(this).text());
       if(arr.indexOf( key ) == -1)
           arr.push(key );
       else
           $(this).text('')    
});​
```

Comment: if i put test1 in last column of last row then it should not be removed

Comment: This removes duplicates across rows now, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements).

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JJj4Z/26/).

```
var seen = {};
$('#removeDupes').on('click', function(){
    $('#test tr td').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var index = $(this).parent('tr').children('td').index(this);
        if (!seen[index]){
            seen[index] = new Array();
        }

        if (seen[index][txt]) {
            $(this).html('&nbsp;');
        }
        else {
            seen[index][txt] = true;
        }
    });
});​
```

Note that your `</td>` elements aren't closed off correctly, and as per ahren's comment, removing the td `entirely` can result in alignment issues.

Comment: This would remove duplicate elements anywhere in the table, not only across rows.