# jquery - remove duplicate consecutive element

Tags: jquery

```
<div>something i need</div>

<span>x</span>

<div>something i need</div>

<span>x</span>

<div>something i need</div>

<span>x</span><span>x</span><span>x</span>

<div>something i need</div>
```

On the row where I have 3 span elements, how do I remove all but one? I only want to have one between each element.

edit: made the html correct so people focus on the actual issue.

Comment: this is wrong html. You cannot put `<span>` between `<li>`

Comment: where are the li elements?

Comment: Where are the 3 li elements

Comment: I changed them to spans because of the first comment. I didn't really write correct html at first, didn't think anyone would point that out considering my issue is not in any way related.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('span').each(function() {
    while($(this).prop('tagName') == $(this).next().prop('tagName'))
        $(this).next().remove();
});
```

As you can see, consecutive spans have been removed, and there is only one `x` in-between the divs instead of three: **http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/KFMrU/**

It would be a good practice to wrap the above elements in a container, and only perform the removal in that container. i.e.:

```
$('#myDiv span').each(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks! I added classes to the spans themselves. Works like a  charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SbpzY/

```
$('div').each( function() {
    if(!$(this).prev().hasClass('a'))
        $(this).remove();
});
```

will work with following html:

```
<span class="a">something i need</span>

<div>x</div>

<span class="a">something i need</span>

<div>x</div>

<span class="a">something i need</span>

<div>x</div><div>x</div><div>x</div>

<span class="a">something i need</span>
```

Comment: Oh dear i started working on it while there was `li` in structure, so i have to create my own.

Answer (score 0):

### Regular Expression

Assuming the HTML elements are directly in the `<body>` then regular expression back-references can also remove the consecutive duplicates, here facilitated by jQuery:

```
const jqContainer = jQuery("body");
jqContainer
    .html(
        jqContainer
            .html()
            .replace(/(<span>[^<>]+<\/span>)+/g, "$1")
    )
;
```

NOTE: The regular expression in this case matches all consecutive duplicate `<span>` elements containing text regardless of what that text is. If you wanted to match `<span>` with specific text within then replace `[^<>]+` with the text to be replaced, e.g. `x`

### CSS

The following may not be applicable in this context, but if the goal is to remove the consecutive duplicate elements for presentation purposes, and if CSS is applicable, then the following CSS will stop the consecutive duplicate spans from being displayed:

```
span + span {
    display: none;
}
```