# JQuery removing specific duplicate row

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tables, I have been using this code to to remove duplicate data found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements):

```
var seen = {};
$('a').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

Works well the problem that I have is if I can't choose which duplicate field to be removed, for example if I have a layout like this, it will remove either the tbody with class="off" or the class without, the rows can be moved so can appear in any order:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="off">
        <tr>
            <td>somedata</td>
        </tr>
    
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>somedata</td>
        </tr>
    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I wondered if anyone knew how to modify the code so that it remove the duplicate that always contained the class="off" or if anyone had any other techniques.

Thanks any help be appreciated.

Comment: Can these off rows ever appear not duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an adapted version of [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822974/1850609) you can use:

```
var seen = {};
$('tbody').each(function() {
    var elmt = {txt: $(this).text(), ref: this};
    if (seen[elmt.txt]) {
        if ($(seen[elmt.txt].ref).hasClass('off')) {
            $(seen[elmt.txt].ref).remove(); seen[elmt.txt].ref = this;
        } else {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
    else
        seen[elmt.txt] = elmt;
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5trzB/2/).

**It will search for all `tbody` with repeated `text()` content.** If it finds a repeated one, it will preferrably remove the one with the `off` class. If none have got it, it will remove the last one found.

Examples:

```xml
The first tbody will prevail:
<table>
    <tbody class="blu"><tr><td>somedata</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody class="off"><tr><td>somedata</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody class="gre"><tr><td>somedata</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

The second tbody will prevail:
<table>
    <tbody class="off"><tr><td>somedata2</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody class="gre"><tr><td>somedata2</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody class="blu"><tr><td>somedata2</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Fantastic this is exactly what I was looking for. Life saver, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jD2Xp/)**

As you wrote:

> I wondered if anyone knew how to modify the code so that it remove the duplicate **that always contained the `class="off"`**.

Just get the `.off` classes and remove them:

```
$('tbody.off').remove();
```

---

### CSS

Also, there is no need to use jQuery. You can hide duplicate items with css:

```
tbody.off { display: none; }
```

- Check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jD2Xp/1/).