# Removing items with duplicate data attribute

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of divs like so

```
<div data-id="001">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="001">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="002">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="002">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="002">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="003">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="003">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="004">Blah Blah Blah</div>
```

Is it possible to scan through this list and remove any items with duplicate data so that I'll end up with something more like:

```
<div data-id="001">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="002">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="003">Blah Blah Blah</div>
<div data-id="004">Blah Blah Blah</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure as you enumerate all the items just keep track of any that you've already found.

```
var found = {};
$('[data-id]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(found[$this.data('id')]){
         $this.remove();   
    }
    else{
         found[$this.data('id')] = true;   
    }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/kpEtQ/

Comment: That'll work, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

See: [JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements)

Instead of checking

```
 $(this).text()
```

check

```
$(this).attr('data-id')
```