# Get Unique DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<span personname="Mr. Bean" class="person person-male"></span>
<span personname="Neo" class="person person-male"></span>
<span personname="Neo" class="person person-male"></span>
<span personname="Trinity" class="person person-female"></span>
<span personname="Trinity" class="person person-female"></span>
<span personname="Neo" class="person person-male"></span>
<span personname="Mr. Bean" class="person person-male"></span>
```

JS:

```
Array.prototype.unique =
    function () {
        var a = [];
        var l = this.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
                // If this[i] is found later in the array
                if (this[i] === this[j])
                    j = ++i;
            }
            a.push(this[i]);
        }
        return a;
};

function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function (i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}

$.unique($('span.person').get()).length // ==> 7
$.unique($('span.person')).length       // ==> 7

$('span.person').get().unique().length  // ==> 7

unique($('span.person').get()).length   // ==> 7
unique($('span.person')).length         // ==> 7
```

How do I get only the unique DOM elements?

That is, `$('span.person).unique().length  // ==> 3`

I am looking for an in-built function, if there is any.

Comment: You need to compare the attributes that you care about, not the elements themselves.

Comment: What do you call `the unique DOM elements`???

Comment: `personname` is not a valid attribute of a span. Instead of using custom attributes, you should use `data-personname`.

Comment: You could use `.first()` or `.last()` or `.eq(x)` or whatever, i'm sorry, i don't really understand what you are expecting here. And be aware, each object are different object even they have same properties. Maybe this is what you are expecting even this is not what suggest your posted code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements

Comment: @Zuck Your edit makes your question clearer for sure

Comment: @Zuck HTML5 has specified `data-XXX` as the place for applications to put custom data. These attributes are reserved for applications, and guaranteed never to conflict with standard attributes. There's an API for it, and jQuery incorporates them into its `.data()` method.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's an ordinary attribute, just using a particular naming scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to get unique `personname`, this will work:

```
function uniquePerson(elements) {
    var results = $();
    var names = {};
    elements.each(function() {
        var name = (this).attr('personname');
        if (!names[name]) {
            results = results.add(this);
            names[name] = true;
        }
    });
    return results;
}
```

All DOM elements are different -- you just want to compare the `personname` attribute, not the whole element.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ZuHaL/3/)