# How to display count of text duplicates removed?

Tags: jquery, count, duplicates

I am using the code to remove duplicates as explained here: [jQuery Remove Duplicate Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements). It works perfectly, but I cannot find the code to show the number of times a duplicate was removed for each element. I think it's quite simple, but I'm not very experienced with jquery.

RESOLVED thanks to [shaunakde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3639582/shaunakde)

```
var seen = {};
var counter = {};
var length = $('#links1 a, #links2 a').length;
console.log(length);
$('#links1 a, #links2 a').each(function(i) {
var txt = $(this).text();
if(seen[txt]){
    $(this).remove();
    counter[txt]++;
}
else{
    seen[txt]=true;
    counter[txt] = 1;
}
if(i==(length-1)){

    $.each(counter , function(i, val) { 
          $('a:contains('+i+')').html(i+' ('+val+')')
```

});

```
}
```

});

It now correctly prints out:
 - Item 1 (4)
 - Item 2 (1)
 - Item 3 (5)

Where the number between brackets is the number of times it was removed (+1).

Comment: make a fiddle for this.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: With this code I just see all items, so they are not removed.

Comment: Just keep count with the dictionary and print the values at the end. `for (var x in seen) console.log(seen[x])` works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/3actv/2/)**

```
var seen = {};
var counter = {};
var length = $('#links1 a, #links2 a').length;              //Length of <a> elements
console.log(length);
$('#links1 a, #links2 a').each(function(i) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if(seen[txt]){
        $(this).remove();
        counter[txt]++;
    }
    else{
        seen[txt]=true;
        counter[txt] = 1; 
    }
    if(i==(length-1)){                                      //Last iteration

        $.each(counter , function(i, val) { 
            $('p#first').append('<p>'+i+': '+val+'</p>');   //Print Text and its Occurence.
        });


    }

});
```

---

You just had to print all the Values and Indexes after the last iteration.

Comment: Yes, this works and prints out the list perfectly, but I need to have the value behind the links that are printed. "#links1 a" refers to links and with the original code it prints correctly those links only once and I need the value behind that. Think we're getting there, thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by getting behind? Can you give an example?

Comment: It prints out the links as: <a href="item1">Item 1</a>. And I want the value behind that (either after or inside the link, doesn't matter). When I try to append your code to the links, I of course get your full text with every link. I only need the count value for the link.

Comment: So do you want to make the output as an `<a>` link? **[Like This](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/3actv/3/)**

Comment: The output is already a link (a copy of the links I'm targeting, with the duplicates removed). And I'd like to have the value of the removed duplicates behind that link.

Comment: So, no, I don't need to add the <a> attribute as it is already there.

Comment: Yes! That works. Thanks a lot! This is the first time I'm asking a question here and I'm already a fan! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd recommend you to create an additional `Array` that counts the duplicates for each `text`

```
counters = Array();

if (seen[txt]) {
    $(this).remove();
    count++;
    counters[txt]++; 
} else {
    seen[txt] = true;
    counters[txt] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, but with your code I still don't see numbers between brackets. Am I missing something? Thanks!