# DOM manipulation to produce unique list of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Says I have DOM like below :

```
<div>
    <span>a</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>c</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>b</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>a</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>b</span>
</div>
```

How to remove duplicated element above? I thought of foreach, text() and remove() but I don't know how to do the comparison.

```
$('div').foreach(function(){
// how to compare here?
$(this).find('span').text();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements)

Comment: @RGraham yo how to alter DOM, not arrays

Comment: Yo. http://jsfiddle.net/5abnag3n/ - copied & pasted from the duplicate, changed the selector