# how to hide redundant element in <li>

Tags: html

I have the following list:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Finspång" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Finspång
  </li>
  <li>
    <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Linköping" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Linköping
  </li>
  <li>
    <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Linköping" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Linköping
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I have two `<li>` with the same name "Linköping".

Is there any way to make it so it only displays unique values?

Comment: Why can't you just remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove it from the source code. So you will have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Finspång" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Finspång
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Linköping" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Linköping
    </li>
</ul>
```

You could also use the keyword `hidden`

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Finspång" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Finspång
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Linköping" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Linköping
    </li>
    <li hidden >
        <input name="tablefilter" type="checkbox" value="Linköping" id="tablefilter1" checked="">Linköping
    </li>
</ul>
```

To show unique values without adding anything to your html code you could make use of jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/8sm6j9kk/

See this post for explanation
[JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements)

> Explanation:
>
> seen is an object which maps any previously seen text to true. It
>   functions as a set containing all previously seen texts. The line if
>   (seen[txt]) checks to see if the text is in the set. If so, we've seen
>   this text before, so we remove the link. Otherwise, this is a link
>   text we see for the first time. We add it to the set so that any
>   further links with the same text will be removed.
>
> An alternative way to represent a set is to use an array containing
>   all values. However, this would make it much slower since to see if a
>   value is in the array we'd need to scan the entire array each time.
>   Looking up a key in an object using seen[txt] is very fast in
>   comparison.

Comment: I can't use this solution because the list is is using Razor to render the values

Comment: Can you with the attached jsfiddle?

Comment: If this solved your question please mark it as solved! :)