# How to remove duplicates in dropdown, jquery

Tags: jquery, unique, dropdown

I've tried to remove duplicates from my dropdown, data I'm working on is corrupted so I need to remove it on dropdowns on my frontend.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var usedNames = {};
   $("#myDropdown").each(RemovingFunction(usedNames));
});


function RemovingFunction (usedNamesObject){
  if (usedNamesObject[this.value]) {
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    usedNamesObject[this.value] = this.text;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myDropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I don't know how to make RemovingFunction work, please help, I need to make this function global to work on my other dropdowns

Comment: I suggest to observe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822974/3887114) first, there is exactly what you need.

Comment: You are immediadely invoking `RemovingFunction` the way you pass it to `each`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fact that the keys of an object are unique to remove any duplicates.

```
//for an object objOpt you can iterate  all the elements like so:  
objOpt[ elementHTML ] = domElement
//of you have 10 similar element, in the end only one makes it to the object
```

```js
$(function() {
    var select = $('#myDropdown');
    var objOpt = {};
    select.find('option').each(function() {
        objOpt[this.outerHTML] = this;
    });
    select.empty();
    for(key in objOpt) {
        select.append( objOpt[key] );
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myDropdown">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
           <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>
```