# How to get first instance of each string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a method in jQuery to find the each element that contains the first instance of a string?

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li> <-- find this
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li> <-- find this
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li> <-- find this
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm.. What should be on the result? The node element for that `<li>` element? Or just the node values (i.e an array like [1, 2, 3])?

Comment: The node element

Comment: Best way you could probably do this is an iteration through nodes and an array of stored innerHTMLs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: Remove duplicate elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822962/jquery-remove-duplicate-elements)

Comment: Ther is not a built-in function in jQuery for this. You should probably re-design the part that builds this HTML if you can.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using a `Set` object to track the `<li>`. Use `filter` to get all all `<li>` objects that is not found on `Set` object.

```js
$(function() {
  var found = new Set();
  var firstLI = $("ul > li").filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    if (!found.has(text)) {
      found.add(text);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });

  //Testting
  firstLI.addClass("first");
});
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li> <!-- find this -->
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li> <!-- find this -->
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li> <!-- find this -->
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Love the usage of Set <3

Comment: You'll want to check browser compatibility before using `Set`. A more compatible way to do the same thing is `var obj = {}`, `obj[key] = true;` to add something to the set, and `if (obj[key])` to check membership.

Comment: Based on Doc, the basic usage of `Set` is compatible even with IE 11. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set.. Or you can use profiler (just to be sure) also :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the elements whose `text()` are distinct from the previous `li's` text. Note this solution only works fine when the `strings` in the list are sorted, as you provided in the sample of input.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var items = $("#ulList li").filter(function()
    {
        return $(this).prev().text() !== $(this).text();
    });

    items.css("background-color", "skyblue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ulList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the list is guaranteed to be sorted then this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()` + `get()` to return an array of the elements' HTML.

Then, use `[...new Set(Array)]` to filter it down to only the unique items.

```js
var elems = $("ul > li").map(function() { return this.outerHTML }).get();
$("ul").html( [...new Set(elems)].join("\n") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

As a reusable function:

```js
const removeDuplicatesFrom = (selector) => {
  const $e = $(selector);
  if (!$e.length) return;

  const children = $e.children().map(function() { return this.outerHTML }).get();
  $e.html([...new Set(children)].join("\n"));
};

removeDuplicatesFrom("ul");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'll want to check browser compatibility before using `...` and `Set`.

Comment: @jnylen Not sure if that's directed at me or OP. OP hasn't specified browser constraints and so I don't think it's useful to preemptively hamstring my answer for Internet Explorer compatibility. Though they can choose not to use this if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).prev("li").html() != $(this).html()){
        $(this).addClass("first");
    }
});
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/seyyedmojtaba72/pen/qGgRxG

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a simple example:

```js
const values = new Set()

$("li").each((idx, element) => {
  values.add(element.textContent)
})

for (let value of values) {
  $(`li:contains('${value}'):first`).addClass("first")
}
```

```css
.first {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```